# Use $refs property from variable to trigger form in vue.js

Tags: forms, vue.js, refs

In my loop I have more forms referenced after their dynamic ID's. But in the $refs plugin I can not give it a dynamic value.
[image]

I want to "ref" to be the value of the parameter

Comment: have you tried `this.$refs[ref].submit()`?

Comment: Great! I have added the response so that other users will see your question as completed.

Answer (score 1):

the solution:

```json
this.$refs[ref].submit()
```

because your `ref` is a string and needs to be inside the `[]` to enable the dot notation.